# How to dynamically count rows in a table from two another tables?

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql, pivot

I want to **count** rows in `CHAT` table that their `REASON_ID` column exist in `REASON_GROUP` table:

First table `Chat`:

```
ID    REASON_ID    DEPARTMENT_ID    
 1      46           1
 2      46           1
 3      50           1
 4      50           2
 5      100          1 
 6      100          2
```

Second table `Reason`:

```
ID    REASON_NAME     REASON_GROUP_ID
46    Reason1         1
50    Reason2         1
100   Reason3         2
101   Reason4         2
105   Reqson5         3
```

Third table `Reason_Group` :

```
ID    NAME
1     Group1
2     Group2
3     Group3
```

I want to display **result** like this:

```
Reason1   Reason2   Reason3   Reason4   Reason5
2         2         2         0         0
```

Comment: Read about pivoting.

Comment: Does it have to be in one row? What about showing the count (name + value) each in a different row?

Comment: Why does your question have mysql and tsql tags? Do you use MS SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PIVOT and dynamic sql for that:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS nvarchar(max)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(REASON_NAME)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REASON_NAME FROM Reason) AS Reasons

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM 
(
    SELECT r.REASON_NAME, SUM(CASE WHEN c.ID is null OR rg.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS cnt 
    FROM Reason r
    LEFT JOIN Chat c ON (c.REASON_ID = r.ID)
    LEFT JOIN Reason_Group rg ON (r.REASON_GROUP_ID = rg.ID)
    GROUP BY REASON_NAME
) inn
    PIVOT(AVG(cnt) 
          FOR REASON_NAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Result:

```
Reason1     Reason2     Reason3     Reason4     Reqson5   
2           2           2           0           0
```

Actually you can do it without PIVOT, but you still have to use dynamic sql, I do not know how you can resolve your task without dynamic sql :(

So this is a solution without PIVOTING:

```
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AgrColumns AS nvarchar(max)

--Get distinct values of the Column 
SELECT @AgrColumns = ISNULL(@AgrColumns + ',', '') + 'SUM(CASE WHEN REASON_NAME = ''' + REASON_NAME + ''' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(REASON_NAME)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REASON_NAME FROM Reason) AS Reasons

--Prepare the query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicQuery =
N'SELECT ' + @AgrColumns + ' FROM 
(
    SELECT r.REASON_NAME, SUM(CASE WHEN c.ID is null OR rg.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS cnt 
    FROM Reason r
    LEFT JOIN Chat c ON (c.REASON_ID = r.ID)
    LEFT JOIN Reason_Group rg ON (r.REASON_GROUP_ID = rg.ID)
    GROUP BY REASON_NAME
) inn'

--Execute the Dynamic Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery
```

Comment: soo tnx for your helpful answer